# Unable to cast Thread.CurrentPrincipal to IClaimsPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wif, thinktecture-ident-server

I am trying to run the [Thinktecture IdentityServer v1](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v1) on my local machine. The problem is that the line

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal
```

always returns `null`.

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is not null, and that type of cast is often described, for example in the [IClaimsPrincipal MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.iclaimsprincipal.aspx).

I did not modify the code of the identity server, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a debugger to check the actual type?

Comment: Note that the various built-in principals did not start inheriting from ClaimsPrincipal until .NET 4.5

Comment: I am facing the same issue,any help?